# How to find game series names from list of titles

Tags: python, pandas

I'm working on a bit of data analysis for a project for school, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to search for help on the specific task.

I have a dataset of [video game sales](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/gregorut/videogamesales) consisting of title, genre, publisher, and sales figures for ~16000 games. As part of the project, I want to take the titles and find series/franchise names (i.e. Super Mario, Pokémon, GTA, etc.) so I can then group them by series.

I have tried searching for just about every variation on "series/franchise from list of titles" I can think of. Most results I get are related to the list or Series data types. The few relevant blogs I can find share nothing about their implementation, and they make it fairly clear that their data is (mostly) uniformly formatted for the task.

Mine is not. The formatting is all over the place: there are numbers, roman numerals, some have a ':' (whether or not it's part of a series).

I'm fairly new to python (only one other project), and very new to all the libraries (pandas and scikit-learn, specifically, which I have never used)

**Are there any decent beginner's guides for this problem? If so, what search terms should I use?**

Any other advice will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Do you have a list of possible game series or do you have to infer it from your data?

Comment: I have to infer it. I suppose I *COULD* compile a basic starter list (a dozen or so series names) manually without too much trouble, but I don't know how well that would cover my dataset.

Comment: I recommend solving the problem of automatic game-series extract first before solving the greater classification problem. Either way, just be warned, someone with more reputation may come and close this question due to SO's "off-topic" and "asking for suggestions" policies. You may benefit from joining a relevant discord channel in your area to discuss these types of projects at length.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey I think this example might help you out. The key things to consider is cleaning as much as possible your data, and then creating key words relating them to a Franchise to later use for labeling the data.

```
import pandas as pd
import re

initial_data = {
    "title": [
        "::gta5",
        ": supermariobros64",
        "Call Of; DutyMW2",
        "CAll of Duty MW3",
        "COD BattleRoyale"
    ],

    "review": [
        "Great game, love killin lol",
        "Rememberd my childhood",
        "I finally was able to fulfill my dream of being in the army",
        "Fullfiled it one more time",
        "Big Maps now, lol"
    ]
}
game_keywords = [
    ('gta', 'Grand Theft Auto'),
    ('grandtheft', 'Grand Theft Auto'),
    ('mariobros', 'Mario Bros'),
    ('call', 'Call Of Duty'),
    ('cod', 'Call Of Duty')
]


df = pd.DataFrame(initial_data)
def search_string(row):
    # We do not want capitalization to discriminate possible results
    title = row['title'].lower()
    
    # This makes sure that your string only contains either letters or numbers
    title = re.sub('[\W_]+', '', title)

    # Iterate over each keyword you defined and return the title
    for kw, game_title in game_keywords:
        if kw in title:
            return game_title
    
    return None


df['Franchise'] = None
df['Franchise'] = df.apply(search_string, axis=1)
df.groupby('Franchise')
df
```